# How do I only read n lines at a time and print in reverse java

Tags: java, collections, stack, bufferedreader

My objective is to only read 50 lines at a time from a text file, print them in reverse order and only store 50 lines a time in memory. In the most efficient way possible.

This is the code I have came up with but the output is not as expected. I have tested it out with an input file of 104 lines.

Actual Output: It prints line 50 to Line 1, Line 101 to Line 52 (skipping line 51), line  104 to 103 (skipping line 102).

Expected Output: Line 50 - Line 1, Line 101 - Line 51, Line 104-102.

I also don't know how to change the first while loop so it keeps going until the end of the file, as testing out while (r.readLine != null) did not work either.

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;


    while (x < 5) {
        for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null && i < 50; line = r.readLine()) {
            s.push(line);
            i++;
        }

        i = 0;

        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            w.println(s.pop());

        }

        x++;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok First thing first

```
for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null && i < 50; line = r.readLine())
```

This for loop is reading one more time reaching 50. That is the main reason of the extra line.

> I also don't know how to change the first while loop so it keeps going
>   until the end of the file

This is because you are not doing correctly. I made a mock up to prints the desired behaviour:

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = r.readLine()) != null){ // Read until end of File
        s.push(strLine); // add to the Stack
        i++;
        if(i==50) // Print if is equal to 50
        {
            while (!s.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(s.pop());
            }
            i=0;
        }
    }

    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(s.pop()); // Print the last numbers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like since you put the

```
line = r.readLine()
```

in the iteration, a line is being read before the check

```
line != null && i < 50
```

That causes a line to be read, than an i to be checked for i<50 and, since i is, indeed, less then 50, the line doesnt get pushed to the stack and we forget it once we are out of the for block.

Try reding line inside a for block. You can still keep the condition for line!=null in the for block, if you want to.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lines()` to create a stream from `BufferedReader` and then take only 50 elements.
smth like

`List<String> lines =  r.lines().limit(50).collect(toList());`

and  then you can iterate from list and print lines;

```
for(int i = lines.size()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
   System.out.println(lines.get(i));
}
```